# Voluptuous: Validate dicts within dicts

Tags: python, validation, dictionary, voluptuous

I'd like to validate the following YAML file defines a `defaultdict` that contains two `dict`s named `dev` and `sha`.

```
 !!python/object/apply:collections.defaultdict
 args:
 - !!python/name:builtins.dict ''
 dictitems:
   dev:
     sha: 5b7
     url: /path/to/here
   shared:
     sha: 58a
     url: /path/to/there
```

using `yaml.load()` (`safe_load()` leads to a whole different question of creating constructors, so let's set that aside.) gives me this data structure:

```
 defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'dev': {'sha': '5b7', 'url': '/path/to/here'}, 
                             'shared': {'sha': '58a', 'url': '/path/to/there'}})
```

I'd like to validate this data structure so I create this:

```
 snapshot_schema = val.Schema({"dictitems":dict,"dev":dict,"shared":dict})
```

This successfully validates that I have one `defaultdict` containing two `dicts`.  I'd like to validate that the `sha` and `url` tags in both of those dicts are really `str` (and more validation later maybe.)

I could create an additional schema

```
 new_schema = Schema({'sha':str, 'url':str})
 new_schema(my_data['dev'])
 new_schema(my_data['shared'])
```

But is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out one answer is to put the `new_schema` into the `snapshot_schema`:

```
   repo_schema = Schema({"sha":str,"url":str})
   snapshot_schema = Schema({"dictitems":dict,"dev":repo_schema,
                                                  "shared":repo_schema})
```

Also I guess you could do:

```
snapshot_schema=Schema({"dictitems":dict,   "dev":{"sha":str,"url":str},
                                         "shared":{"sha":str,"url":str})
```